# Remove last empty line in XML generated by Jdom2

Tags: java, xml, jdom

I used `getPrettyFormat()` in Jdom2 and it gives me a XML file as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <courses>
      <name id="1">CynO</name>
   </courses>
```

My XML file generate 5 lines instead of 4. How to delete the fifth empty line?

My code:

```
XMLOutputter xml = new XMLOutputter();
xml.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());
xml.output(doc, new FileWriter(fileName));
```

Comment: Why would you want to explicitly not end a file with a newline?

Comment: 1. Output the formatted XML to a string. 2. Call the ```.strip()``` method of the string. 3. Write the string to a file.